# ERROR: Could not find migration method: up

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize-cli

I have the up option filed in my seed file, but I couldn't find what the message exactly says. This error occurs when I run the command `npx sequelize-cli db:seed:all` As per the [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59406974/could-not-find-migration-method-up) I added the .sequelizerc file as well but it throws same error. Why this error occurs and how to solve it ? I am a beginner in node js ORM, please help me resolve it. Thanks in advance.

*Note:* The data was added in the db as expected

**demoUser.js**

```js
'use strict';
const Data = require('./data.js')
const data = new Data()

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.bulkInsert('Users', [{
      firstName: "a",//data.getUserStats(),
      lastName: 'Doe',
      email: 'example@example.com',
      createdAt: new Date(),
      updatedAt: new Date()
    }]); 
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.bulkDelete('Users', null, {});
  }
};
```

Full path to demoUser.js `../seeders/20200824140115-demo-user.js`

**.sequelizerc**

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  'config': path.resolve('config', 'config.json'),
  'models-path': path.resolve('models'),
  'seeders-path': path.resolve('seeders'),
  'migrations-path': path.resolve('migrations')
};
```

Comment: Can you try removing the `async` ?

Comment: @SerShubham It remains the same even after removing the async

Comment: Can you show your `.sequelizerc` file and the full path of `demoUsers.js` from the root of application?

Comment: Added .sequelizerc and the path for the demoUser.js file. Thanks @tbking

Comment: What is the location for your `.sequelizerc` and from which directory you are running the seed command. More over you can add the basic directory structure of the project.